# Reset board on Tic-Tac-Toe

Tags: javascript

I'm trying my hand at building a tic-tac-toe game with plain vanilla Javascript, so I'm hoping we can stay in the boundaries of keeping it simple Javascript. Do not optimize code, trying to learn the hard way!

What I require is the following: After all squares have been filled, an alert box appears "All squares filled!" <-- This part is done. After the user clicks on the OK box, a reset button appears towards the bottom of the board. This reset button will reset the board so the game can be played again. After clicking the reset button, the board should reset and the reset button should disappear.

I have started the function called 'function resetButton'. If you need further clarification, please advise.

Thank you!

Here is the code I have got so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
    <style>
        td {

            border: 1px solid black;
            height: 250px;
            width: 250px;
            font-family: sans-serif;
            font-size: 150pt;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" id="square1" onclick="displayMarker('square1');"></td>
            <td align="center" id="square2" onclick="displayMarker('square2');"></td>
            <td align="center" id="square3" onclick="displayMarker('square3');"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" id="square4" onclick="displayMarker('square4');"></td>
            <td align="center" id="square5" onclick="displayMarker('square5');"></td>
            <td align="center" id="square6" onclick="displayMarker('square6');"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" id="square7" onclick="displayMarker('square7');"></td>
            <td align="center" id="square8" onclick="displayMarker('square8');"></td>
            <td align="center" id="square9" onclick="displayMarker('square9');"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <script>

        var cp1 = 1;

        function displayMarker(allSquares) {

            if (document.getElementById(allSquares).innerHTML != "") {
                alert("Choose another square");
            }
            else {

                if (cp1 == 1) {
                    document.getElementById(allSquares).innerHTML = "X";
                    cp1 = 2;
                }

                else {
                    document.getElementById(allSquares).innerHTML = "O";
                    cp1 = 1;
                }
            }
            checkEmpty();
        }

        function checkEmpty() {

            var anyEmpty = false;
            for (var i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
                if (document.getElementById('square' + i).innerHTML == "") {
                   anyEmpty = true;
                }
            }

            if (!anyEmpty)
                alert("All squares filled!");

             resetButton();
        }

        function resetButton() {

            var button = document.createElement("button");
            button.innerHTML = "Reset";



            button.addEventListener("click", function () {
                alert("Board Reset");
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ...so you wrote a method stub and want someone to fill it in for you? That's not how Stack Overflow works. What specifically are you having trouble with?

Comment: "If you need further clarification".  What have *you* written for the reset?  Where are you stuck with the reset functionality, and no, "writing it" is not an acceptable response.

Comment: You already have a function that loops over all the cells and checks their content, just use the same logic only set the content to nothing (empty string).

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this..

```
button.addEventListener("click", function () {
    var tds = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
    for(var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
        tds[i].innerHTML = ''
    }
});
```

Comment: The OP already has a function to loop over all the TDs used for the game. This function is less suitable as it will replace the content of every TD in the document, not just those used for the game.